# Kindle ignores mutt emails

Tags: macos, mutt, imap

### Problem Summary

kindle ignores epub attachments send to the kindle address (`<x>@kindle.com`) when using mutt but not with gmail. (same sender address)

### System Specs

- Apple Silicon MacBook Pro 2021 running macOS Sonoma 14.1
- mutt version 2.2.12

### Background

I have mutt set up to use Gmail IMAP. when I send an email through mutt, it shows up as sent in the gmail web interface.

The command looks like this:

```bash
echo "Body" | mutt -s "Subject" -a attachment.epub -- mykindle@kindle.com
```

### Some Leads

When I checked both emails, the one from mutt had `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` while the one sent from the gmail web interface had `application/epub+zip`. This was the only difference between the two emails. When I create a `~/.mime.types` file with `.epub    application/epub`, it changes nothing

### In Conclusion

What can I do to correct this difference in `Content-Type`? Is there another issue? Thank you for answering!